# Send PDF via Email with PHP Script

Tags: php, pdf, email-attachments, acrobat

I've seen the other questions/answers in StackOverflow but I cannot for the life of me get this to work correctly, and I'm really curious to see what I'm doing wrong.

An insurance company has PDFs that they'd like their customers to fill online and submit via their site. The PDF form will be sent via email as a PDF attachment all filled out.

I have a PHP script that sends the PDF, but it's not saving form data (names, addresses, etc.). It's only sending the blank PDF.  Here's the code:

```
<?php
$fileatt = "file-name.pdf";
$fileatt_type = "application/pdf";
$fileatt_name = "file-name.pdf";

$email_from = "From"; // Who the email is from
$email_subject = "Form"; // The Subject of the email
$email_message = "Text.";

$email_to = "someemail@gmail.com"; // Who the email is to

$headers = "De: ".$email_from;

//no need to change anything else under this point

$file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
$data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
fclose($file);

$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

$email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
$email_message .= "\n\n";

$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

$email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
" name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
//"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
//" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data .= "\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

$ok = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

if($ok) {
    echo 'Sent...';
  //unlink($fileatt); //NOW WE DELETE THE FILE FROM THE FOLDER pdfs
}
else {
    echo 'Error...';
}
?>
```

I appreciate any input/feedback. I've thought about using PHPMailer but I think this is like 99% done and I'm curious to see what it's missing?

(The PDF file was created with Word then using Adobe Acrobat Pro all the input fields and the submit button was created, the submit button points to the PHP script that sends the PDF)

Comment: You have written a lot of bespoke code there and it might be an idea to use a framework that will take care of all this for you. Yes it's interesting to know what's wrong with that code but at the end of the day you just want to get the job done.

Comment: @JeremyQuinton Yesterday I wrote it with PHP Mailer and I still get the exact same result, I can receive the PDF form when I hit the submit form within the PDF, but it's blank!!!

Comment: I'm practically not saving any data, I've tried several methods but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...